# Extending name of variable in a loop

Tags: python

suppose I have some numbers (1, 2, 3) and I want to assign each of these numbers to other variables with names `a1`, `a2`and `a3` (that is, `a1=1`, `a2=2`, and `a3=3`). I would be thankful to know how it is possible to do this through a for loop in python.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321886/dynamic-variables-in-python)

Comment: You should use a `dict` and not try to make variable names dynamically

Comment: Actually, I want to define different variables. Here, I want to define 3 variables not rename a single variable.

Comment: @Nahil: actually you can, but it is a horrible idea.

Comment: @CoryKramer way is right thing to do.

Comment: This is a common beginner request, but is actually a terrible idea for reasons that can be difficult to explain to a beginner (there are unfortunately lots of pitfalls like this in programming). For now, take the received wisdom that you don't actually want to do this and solve the problem another way.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, but I truly recommend using a `dict`.

To do this you can set the `globals()`

***not recommended***

(Stealing JoshuaF's one-liner)

```
for n in numbers:
    globals()['a%s' % n] = n
```

**or**

```
globals().update(('a%s' % n, n) for n in numbers)
```

Instead, using a `dict`

***recommended***

```
>>> d = {'a%s' % n:n for n in numbers}
>>> d['a1']
1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using `globals()` dictionary:

```
l = (1, 2, 3)

for i in l:
    globals()["a" + str(i)] = i

print(a1, a2, a3)
```

Output:

> 1 2 3

Comment: This being said, dynamically modifying globals is usually a bad idea. It's hard to tell which variables are defined from looking at the code (plus if you use an IDE it will be very sad).

Comment: What can I say @JoshuaF? I agree with you, but OP surely know, what he/she is doing...

Comment: Also, a bit neater might be `globals().update(('a{}'.format(i),  i) for i in l)`

Comment: Dear @AndrejKesely. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this summarized assignment method;

```
a1, a2, a3 = 1, 2, 3
print(a1,a2, a3)
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what if there are 100 values and therefore 100 variable?

Comment: If you have 100 values in a list, the indexes of the values are enough to fetch them, no need to sweat with variables.