# How do I use a variable that is built from other variables?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a dynamic URL with some of the information stored in a list. I have loaded the list with some values and then iterate through the list concatenating the value from the list with a prefix. I then want to reference that concatenated value which matches a preloaded variable.

In the below code url_var just returns the name of the variable but not the value of the variable.

```
base_url_asia = "https://www.location1.com/"
base_url_americas = "https://www.location2.com/"

regions = [asia, americas]

for i in range(len(regions)):
    url_var = 'base_url_' + regions[i]
    print(url_var)
```

I expect the output to be the full URL however all I get is base_url_asia or base_url_americas and not the actual url.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: The shown code does not work, since both ‚asia‘ and ‚americas‘ are undefined names. Please show the actual code you are having a problem with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321886/dynamic-variables-in-python)

Comment: Thank you John Coleman, dictionaries appears to be the answer. I am learning python as I go and never had used them before. Now to figure out how to mark your answer as the correct one I will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining variables that you are not using. 'base_url_' is a string and not a variable. If you want to store different locations using the same variable but with different names, you should use a dictionary.

```py
base_url=dict()
base_url['asia'] = 'www.location1.com'
base_url['americas'] = 'www.location2.com'

continent = ['asia','americas']

for cont in continent:
    print(base_url[cont])
```

Note that cont is not an integer, but is the name of the continents.

I hope you find it useful. Good luck!